# Swipable Cell with Prototype Cell on Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have prepared my cell on storyboard and inherited my class from Swipable cell class. But there is no action on swipe. Is it possible to do it on storyboard or Do I need to do it on an hardcoded way.

My Cell Class is as below;

```
@interface SpendListExtendedTableViewCell : MGSwipeTableCell

@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton *installments;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *cardTypeImageView;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *last4DigitLabel;
@end
```

In my VC;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cardSpentList";

SpendListExtendedTableViewCell *cell = [_cardSpentList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [feedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if([[tempDict objectForKey:@"cardType"] isEqualToString:@"V"])
    [cell.cardTypeImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"visa2.png"]];
else
    [cell.cardTypeImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mclogo2.png"]];

[cell.last4DigitLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",[tempDict objectForKey:@"cardLast4Digit"]]];

cell.amount = [tempDict objectForKey:@"spendAmount"];
cell.delegate2 = self;
cell.delegate = self;

cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = 2;

cell.rightButtons = [self createRightButtonsForMyFollows:1];
cell.rightButtons = [self createRightButtonsForStocks:3];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

//NSLog(@"%@",liveScoreObject.currentMinuteStatus);

return cell;

}
```

setRightButtons

```
-(NSArray *) createRightButtonsForStocks: (int) number
{
NSMutableArray * result = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString* titles[3] = {@"Sat",@"Al",@"İzle"};
UIColor * colors[3] = {[UIColor redColor], [UIColor blueColor],[UIColor brownColor]};
for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i)
{
    MGSwipeButton * button = [MGSwipeButton buttonWithTitle:titles[i] backgroundColor:colors[i] callback:^BOOL(MGSwipeTableCell * sender){
        NSLog(@"Convenience callback received (right).");
        return YES;
    }];
    [result addObject:button];
}
return result;
}
```

What might be the wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using any library to swipe tableview cell?

Comment: yes, MGSwipeTableViewCell library @EktaMakadiya

Comment: Can you show createRightButtonsForMyFollows method?

Comment: @EktaMakadiya i have added the method